# HTML/CSS Horizontally align Radio and Images labels

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I try to align horizontally my images with my radio boxes :

Here is the code i'm using :

```html
<div class="radio46">
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="J"> <img class="couleur" src="Img.jpg" width="20" height="20" border="0" alt="Jaune">
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="V"> <img class="couleur" src="Img2.jpg" width="20" height="20" border="0" alt="Vert">
</div>
```

And the CSS applied to it :

```
.radio46{
font-size: 15px;
opacity: 0.5;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
line-height:15px;
}
```

However, i can't figure out how to fix it.

May you please help me ?

Answer (score 2):

add the following to your css

```
input, img{display:inline;
vertical-align:middle;}
```

[Output](http://jsbin.com/taseqodiji)

Answer (score 1):

You can center it using Flexbox

```
.radio46 {
    opacity: 0.5;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Or the traditional way

```
.radio46 {
    opacity: 0.5;   
}
input, img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dieguezz/douju2tf/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.radio46 * 
{
    vertical-align: middle;                
}
```

You can see it working when the height of image is relatively bigger.